# Exibir Carrossel depois de carregado

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

Tenho dois carrosséis na pagina e enquanto eles estão carregando, ficam quebrados. Só depois que ficam certos. Eu gostaria que eles só fossem exibidos, depois de carregados por completo, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
window.onload = function() {
            $('#corpo-conteudo-imoveis1').fadeIn(1500)
            $("#pikame").PikaChoose({carousel:true, carouselVertical:true});
            $("#pikame2").PikaChoose({carousel:true, carouselVertical:true});
        };
```

Comment: seu script está na tag head do seu html?

Answer (score 2):

Olá.

Na própria documentação da ferramenta tem uma opção **fadeThumbsIn** que diz o seguinte:

> Enabling this will fade in the UL after PikaChoose has loaded. You
>   must manually set the UL to display:none in your CSS for this to have
>   an effect. 
>   $("#id").PikaChoose({fadeThumbsIn: true});

Documentação http://www.pikachoose.com/versions/

Então imagino que você possa fazer assim:

```
window.onload = function() {
        $('#corpo-conteudo-imoveis1').fadeIn(1500)
        $("#pikame").PikaChoose({carousel:true, carouselVertical:true, fadeThumbsIn: true});
        $("#pikame2").PikaChoose({carousel:true, carouselVertical:true, fadeThumbsIn: true});
    };
```

Outra opção que a ferramenta oferece é utilizar callbacks.

Existe o callback **buildFinished** que diz o seguinte:

> buildFinished: called as soon as PikaChoose is done building the
>   slideshow

E fala que o modo de utlizar é:

> function myFunction(self){ console.log(self); }
>   $("#id").PikaChoose({buildFinished: myFunction});

Então nesse caso, você pode começar com todos seus elementos escondidos.

```
$("#pikame").hide();
$("#pikame2").hide();
```

E fazer sua função mostrar eles, da seguinte forma (por exemplo).

```
function habilitaSlideShow(self) {
     $(self).fadeIn();
}

window.onload = function() {
        $('#corpo-conteudo-imoveis1').fadeIn(1500)
        $("#pikame").PikaChoose({carousel:true, carouselVertical:true, buildFinished: habilitaSlideShow});
        $("#pikame2").PikaChoose({carousel:true, carouselVertical:true, buildFinished: habilitaSlideShow});
    };
```

Mais informações na sessão **API Hooks** do link http://www.pikachoose.com/versions/

Comment: Caramba, não expandi essa seção da na documentação e fui procurar o evento no código fonte.. hahaha